# Weird deformation with fingers (automatic weights)

Tags: rigging

Hello i was rigging an arm for my game and there's this bug if i rotate my fingers this deformation happens, How can i fix this? This is using automatic weights
I tried using other types but it didn't work, I tried redoing the rig but still same bug.
What i'm trying to do is not to make the hand move but the fingers, The fingers should move the fingers, not the hand.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXSjV.jpg

Comment: hard to help, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=KyMqRwKM" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/KyMqRwKM/)

Answer (score 0):

The rigging is bad: Select the armature, shift select the object, switch to *Weight Paint* mode, then select each bone, you’ll see what part of the mesh they affect. You can see that the first thumb phalanx affects the palm, which is not supposed to do. Some other phalanx also affect the palm.

[image]

So you need to:

- Create a bone for the palm itself
- Parent this bone to the last arm bone (*Keep Offset* mode).
- Parent each first phalanx to this bone (*Keep Offset* mode).

[image]

- In Weight Paint mode, paint the influence of the palm bone (enable the *2D Falloff* option to paint through the mesh).

[image]

- Also remove all the unnecessary influences.

[image]

Now it works fine (don't know why your arm has 3 bones though).

[image]

Comment: thank you so much!